# Difference between Potato Pancake and Hash Browns?

Tags: potatoes, language

I was wondering what was the difference between these two potato recipes? Both of them seem to be near same but are referred differently. Is there even a difference or is it just word play?

Comment: When you say 'potato pancakes', I assume you mean latkes or similar recipes where shreded potato is shallow fried in oil ... but there's also matafan, which is a Provincal French griddle cake made with mashed potato.

Comment: and related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13102/67

Comment: @Joe yeah specifically I was talking about Latkes. Didn't know about matafan! Very interesting :) and thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potato pancakes are held together, usually with egg, sometimes flour as well. Hash Browns are usually just the potato, maybe onion and seasonings.

Comment: ahh I suspected it was the egg but I wasn't sure. Thank you :)

Comment: Hash browns can also be cooked on a griddle ... latkes are *always* fried (I've been the name translates to 'little oily thing')