# Is there any way to make an egg pancake without sugar or white flour?

Tags: breakfast

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make a healthy breakfast pancake that I can put in a container and take to work with me.

Most pancakes need white flour and sugar; but is there something that can be made with oatmeal or something similar?  (Low-GI carbs basically)

Comment: There are tons of [recipes](http://www.topwithcinnamon.com/2013/01/2-ingredient-healthy-pancakes-gluten-free-dairy-free.html) out there. I've never tried them so I can't say much but... try searching.  The linked recipe uses only banana and egg.

Comment: If you're curious, this is the search I did to find that recipe: https://www.google.com/search?q=healthy+pancake+gluten+free+recipe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13102/67

Comment: It's possible that if you clarified this there might be a real question here, but as-is, it's a recipe request (off topic) and a vague one at that, so I'm afraid I'll have to close it.

Answer (score 4):

You likely need to define 'egg pancake', because to me, it would seem that the ideal solution would be something without flour or sugar at all -- an omelette.

And there are many other similar items that could also qualify, if you want more than just eggs in there -- if you add potato, you can make the Jewish latkes (aka, 'potato pancakes') or Spanish tortilla de patatas.  If you used mashed potatoes and a little bit of a flour (not necessarily wheat), you could make French matafan (which looks more like an American pancake).

If you add shreaded vegetables, and mayme some sort of flour (again, not necessarily wheat), you can make the Japanese okonomiyaki or the Korean jeon.

If you use cornmeal instead of wheat flour, you can make the New England (likely Native American in origin) jonnycakes -- some recipes call for sugar and/or some wheat flour, but there are plenty that don't.

If you're really set on using oats, then look for recipes for Scottish oatcakes (again, some recipes call for sugar and flour, but not all).  Although they're cooked like a pancake (or 'drop scone' for the Brits), they come out more cookie-like in texture.  (or biscuit-like for the Brits).

**update** : I should've also mentioned that many of the items that I've listed are can be served at room temp, which makes them ideal for transporting ... and while adding this, I remembered that you said 'slow carbs' ... so the potato-based ones are out.  The tortilla de patatas or the matafan could likely be made with sweet potatoes instead.  For the latkes, I'd specifically look for a recipe that calls for sweet potato, rather than trying to adapt it on your own.  And for those without the potato restriction, there's also German potato pancakes (which can be similar to latkes)

Answer (score 2):

[Pancakes made with besan flour](https://www.google.com/search?q=besam%20pancakes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=besan%20pancakes&spell=1) (garbanzo bean flour, [Gram flour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_flour), chickpea flour) can be quite tasty even without adding an egg. For variety, you can add all sorts of crazy things to the basic flour/milk or water/salt recipe.
The stuff can be hard to find. Usually Indian stores carry it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, yes. A traditional option will be to make buckwheat pancakes and not sweeten them. But note that buckwheat pancakes still have white flour, so you'll have to tweak somewhat.

The problem is that all nonwheat flours lack gluten, so your pancakes will be prone to rising badly and falling apart. The easiest option is to add vital gluten to the nonwheat flour, it is a protein, so it does not change your carbs calculations. The ratio should be around 10% gluten to 90% flour.

If you can't find gluten, your options are much more limited. You'll probably need to still use a significant proportion of wheat flour (25 to 50%) mixed with the other flour. And you'll have to put up with inferior texture, and be much more precise in temperature and shape control while baking them, to prevent falling apart. Also, making mini pancakes will help.

As for the sugar, it is only there for taste and some browning. My suggestion is to leave it out completely, a pancake does not have to be sweet. The lighter color is less appetizing, but not tragic. You can also use artificial sweeteners if you insist on sweeter pancakes, although it wouldn't be my choice, they often have an off taste. Natural sweeteners are simply different sugars, and it's up to you to know if your diet allows you to use them.

The above assumes that you can have flour of some kind - grain flour, not almond "flour" or other milled nuts. Of course, oatmeal flour has a much higher GI than whole oatmeal. If you can't have flours, you can't have anything pancake like, the best you can hope for is some kind of omelette. And if you are there, mixing whole grains into it is not going to add anything tastewise, so you are better off experimenting in other directions.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned; skipping the flour all together usaully results in something that is not a pancake. So it really depends on if you want 0 gluten/gi or just low GI.

For low GI; you can do many recipes and typically replace 3/4ths of the flour with some other product.

Have used; rolled oats, buckwheat, flax seed, rice flour, etc... Many of the red mills products have gluten free or low GI flour subs you can play with.

Have tried skipping flour all together; never comes out well.

For sugar part; any favorite fruit will work well instead; either cooked in or added when you eat.  (i used to make a fruit yogurt spread; instead of syrup)