# How to make crispy crepes?

Tags: crepe

I make very thin crepes using batter made of 500 grams of flour, 3 eggs and 250 ml of milk. They turn out thin, soft and pliable. My wife on the other hand remembers fondly her mothers crepes, which used to be a bit thicker and had a bit of crunch.

How should I modify my recipe or technique to make them more like that? I'm guessing using more fat (I try to use as little as possible) could help, but then I run into problems spreading the batter over the pan surface.

Comment: As you mention both 'thicker' and 'crispy', you might want to not look at French crepe recipes, but at various other countries' pancake recipes: pancakes (England), pannekoeken (Netherlands), pannkakor (Sweden), pannekaken (Norway), pfannkuchen (Germany).   Also see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/72915/67

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A crisp crepe is less about the recipe and more about the cooking technique. You simply need to leave it a little longer before flipping it, allowing the edges to crisp. A *little* more oil than usual will help, but it should still only be a thin coating wiped on with a paper towel.

To make a thicker crepe, simply use less liquid. You can also look at using alternative flours like buckwheat which alter the texture.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not filling the crepe: just cook it a little longer. 
If you are filling the crepe:
Depending on what you're filling the crepe with, you can put in the oven for a few minutes after it's filled. This way, it will be soft and flexible when you're filling it but will get crispier after it's filled.

Comment: The OP said nothing about fillings...

Answer (score 1):

Less eggs or none. Just as with cookies, eggs will make them cakier.
And lower temperature longer cooking time will help too as it gives time for the batter to spread out and evaporate moisture.
Corn syrup instead of sugar helps as granulated sugar holds water.

The easiest, surefire way, is to make them ahead of time, let them dry a bit, fill and roll, refry on hot griddle.

Comment: It's funny, because here in the Czech Republic we barely if ever use corn syrup. I am also pretty sure she would not skip the eggs, although the exact ratio could be put to question there :-).

Comment: I am surprised that you consider eggs to make them cakey. I have never seen crepe recipes without eggs (I would probably consider them something different like a tortilla), and my own recipe has more eggs and is certainly not cakelike.

Comment: In the US, people think because an immigrant made something it's "authentic" when it's just watered down pancake mix and the peculiarities of the pans they use and smelling spices used in other dishes coming from the kitchen. Also, today's much higher gluten flour provides a lot more bonding, hence less eggs.

Comment: Ingredients, cooking pans, oil/fat are different today than in grandma's time; what we are going after is the effect, appearance, the texture and essential taste (is it the crepe flavor or the syrup/jam?). 98% of people won't detect differences in ingredients.