# Latkes variations

Tags: vegetables, oil, ingredient-selection, kosher

What various types of latkes are there? I mean besides the classic potato latke. I mostly curious as to Jewish foods for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latke translates into 'little oily thing', so really it's anything small and fried.

Potatoes are a new world crop, and the celebration of oil as a part of Hanukkah goes back much further.  The [original latkes were actually made with cheese](http://www.pbs.org/food/features/history-of-latkes/)

But most people today associate them with any sort of shredded, fried vegetables.  Most anything starchy will work (zucchini or other squash, root vegetables, etc.)

Comment: (the translation being from my Jewish boss when I did my [pancakes project](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13102/67)), but other confirmation : http://www.balashon.com/2006/12/latke.html