# how to tell if a whipping cream dispenser is overpressurized or underpressurized?

Tags: equipment, whipped-cream, whipper

The question is simple - how to tell if a whipping cream dispenser is overpressurized or underpressurized without the risk of removing the head?

Note: Initially I submitted two questions in [another single post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34657/how-to-disarm-a-potentially-pressurized-whipping-siphon) (where you can read the background for my question), but only one got a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pressure gauge on these devices, nor is one available even on the professional line according to iSi's website. I don't think it is possible to determine the pressure inside

Comment: There is no pressure gauge on my bicycle tire, but I can tell when it is a bit overpressurized for comfortable riding, and I can certainly tell when it is underpressurized. For a whipping cream dispenser, it is possible that one can judge how the pressure deviates from the optimum by the quality of the cream coming out of it.