# straining methods for liquids to be used in whipping siphon

Tags: equipment, whipper

I'm starting to use a whipping siphon and [in a previous question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34657/how-to-disarm-a-potentially-pressurized-whipping-siphon) some comments mentioned that "it's really easy to clog the dispenser" and "if you can perceive particulate when the mix is on your tongue, it's still too chunky for the whipper."

Which devices (e.g. "cheesecloth" or "strainer of Brand X/style Y") would be best to use to make sure that the mix is smooth enough to minimize or eliminate the risk of it clogging the whipping siphon?

Comment: look up "chinois", this is the finest filter used in pro cooking

Answer (score 1):

For the non-professional coffee filters are the best bet. If you want to go a bit further get some disposable laboratory filters, they can trap smaller particles. You wanna go below 25 microns for the food to be imperceptible in the tongue.

Answer (score 1):

When I make mole sauce, I process it through a food mill to get out all the chili skins. The sauce is very smooth after going through the food mill. Use the finest hole insert it comes with.

Other then that, I use to use a fine strainer and push the mole sauce through, but it took a lot more time and effort.

If you try the food mill approach, you may want to test the resulting sauce by pushing it through cheese cloth to see how fine the sauce (or what ever you are pushing through the syphon) got.